# Pandas module not found after reinstalling Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

after making some changes on my system Python can no longer find Pandas. I'll first cover off the error and then what I've tried to correct the issue.

Error - If I'm reading this correctly `Python.exe` cannot find pandas...
System - Hyper-v 2016, Python 3.5.4, Pandas 0.23 installed to c:\Python35.

Issue - there were previous instances of Python installed in different locations. I removed these and deleted directories `C:\Program Files etc` prior to installing 3.5.4 but I suspect there's a reference somewhere.

Troubleshooting.

Is recognizing the right version

```
`C:\Python35>python
Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit         (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.r`
```

System is seeing right location

```
import os, sys
folder=os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
print(folder)here
```

OTHER

I have tried reinstalling pandas with `pip install --ignore-installed` pandas which says it completes successfully.

I have inspected the directory `C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core` . All *.py files mentioned in the error exist.

The script I am running works on a W10 machine with P3.5.4 installed to `c:\Python35`.

The `pip freeze` command shows `pandas 0.23.0` is installed

Any tips on how to troubleshoot appreciated

ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\SQL\Script\Python\ASXList.py", line 4, in <module>
import pandas as pd
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
from pandas.core.api import *
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in <module>
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 49, in <module>
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 74, in <module>
from pandas.core.series import Series
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3978, in <module>
Series._add_series_or_dataframe_operations()
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8891, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
from pandas.core import window as rwindow
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 36, in <module>
import pandas._libs.window as _window
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

The error seems to be with pandas .23 do the following in the command prompt.

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas == 0.22
```

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21106

Comment: Yes - to expand at the issue heading i did the following.

Comment: Uninstalled Python, deleted residual directories and then reinstalled python, then addins with PIP. ie. pandas

Comment: just rereading your note....which is about pandas not python. I havn't uninstalled pandas. I will try that and report back

Comment: Uninstalling -> reinstalling pandas did not correct...also tried uninstalling required packages python-dateutil, numpy, pytz, six in addition to pandas and then reinstall pandas, Did not fix

Comment: Did you do anything else with Windows? It seems like a missing dll file is related to a missing windows piece.

Comment: 'Did you do anything else with Windows?' Not that I can recall. Pandas was working a day ago before I started messing with the above.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - pandas 0.22 did the trick on the hyper-v system in question running py3.5.4. Interestingly my W10 machine is running pandas 0.23 and py3.5.4 and does not through the error...Its working though and that's good enough for the time being.

Comment: That is weird. The windows is the first c++ file so it maybe related to that. In the link they had a fix for it but it doesn’t seem to have been released yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the path that contains the `pandas` module to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. For example, if `pandas` is at `C:\Python35`, then set the environment variable to that path. Then when you run python again, the interpreter will know where to look for the `pandas` module.

Instruction on setting the environment variable can be found at https://www.codingdefined.com/2015/09/how-to-set-up-pythonpath-in-windows-10.html

Comment: I selected this on the install but did not make a difference in my case. The machine in question is a gui less hyper v. I'd need to further research how to set environment variables from the cmd line to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by installing Anaconda.
Then, in VS Code, make sure you are in the right environment. 
For me it is: python 3.76 64bit ('base':conda). 
You can see this on the botton purple line in VS Code, and you can click on this and change it to the correct one.. then I typed 'import pandas as pd' and it worked for the first time! :)